# display none set by jquery getting reverted on an api call, why its happening?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a code for hiding an accordion when the code start execute.

```
 if ($localStorage.refinedItemId) {

    $('#searchSection').css('display', 'none');
    console.log($('#searchSection').css('display')); //getting none as expected

    $http.get(Url.GetRefineItemById + "/" + $scope.refinedItemId).success(function (data) {
        console.log($('#searchSection').css('display')); // getting block as output, how its getting reverted on call of an api?
}
```

so when the api calls and on success the `display: none` property of the accordion getting reverted to block, how its happening, i am not making it display block anywhere. What should I do to avoid this problem?

Comment: you don't have any `ng-hide="changeable_value"` or `ng-show` on that element which value may change before it get to `$http success`?

Comment: i can do it using ng-hide using newly created variable, but its not the right way, accordian is expected to toggle between display : none and block

Comment: Want to to know why its behaving like this

Comment: no, I was saying that to be sure that is not changing elsewhere because as you may know `$http` is an async call and `success` does not trigger immediately, so the rest of your code may get executed before success happen